Movie about guy marrying his boss to avoid deportation?
I guess this movie would be classified as a romantic comedy.
The movie is about a female who had a high position in a company in the US, and made the workers work really hard. She was a Canadian immigrant though, and was about to be deported back to Canada, but to avoid that she went to Alaska with one of her employees in order to marry him. At first the employee does it in order not to lose his job, but after a while he starts liking the woman. 
The movie shouldn't be that old, I would b surprised if it were older than 2005.

Sounds like The Proposal from 2009 with Sandra Bullock and Ryan Reynolds:

For three years, Andrew Paxton has slaved as the assistant to Margaret Tate, hard-driving editor at a New York publisher. When Margaret, a Canadian, faces deportation for an expired visa, she hatches a scheme to marry Andrew - he agrees if she'll promise a promotion. A skeptical INS agent vows to test the couple about each other the next Monday. Andrew had plans to fly home that weekend for his grandma's 90th, so Margaret goes with him - to Sitka, Alaska - where mom, dad, and grams await.

They start liking each other, of course. Here's the trailer:




Yeah sure you got it!
